# My kivy Scrollview behaves differently in touch event and mouse scroll event

Tags: python, kivy, scrollview, mousewheel

I made a windows application using Kivy(v.1.10.1) and Python(v.3.6.6) under VS code. I want to use ScrollView below BoxLayout. However, it does not work well. In other words, it scrolls two times(attached image) when using mouse scroll but scrolls only one time when using touch screen. My goal is single scrolling using mouse wheel. What should I do? Please help me!

my kivy code

```
    #:kivy 1.10.1
<Test>:    
    BoxLayout:
        orientation:'vertical'
        size:root.size
        AnchorLayout:
            id:upper_bar
            anchor_x:'left'
            anchor_y:'top'
            ActionBar:
                size_hint_y:None
                size_hint_x:1
                height:30
                ActionView:
                    ActionPrevious:
                        with_previous: False
                        title:''
                        app_icon:''
                    ActionGroup:
                        text:'File'
                        mode:'spinner'
                        ActionButton:
                            text:'Open'
                        ActionButton:
                            text:'Add New Obj'

        AnchorLayout:
            id:main_field
            anchor_x:'center'
            anchor_y:'center'
            size_hint_y:None
            size_hint_x:1
            height:root.height - upper_bar.height - lower_bar.height
            ScrollView:
                id:main_field
                do_scroll_y:True
                pos_hint: {'top': 1}
                ScatterLayout:
                    size_hint:[None,None]
                    size:1000,1000
                    canvas:
                        Rectangle: 
                            pos:10,10
                            size:100,200
                        Rectangle: 
                            pos:300,150
                            size:100,200

        AnchorLayout:
            id:lower_bar
            size_hint_y:None
            size_hint_x:1
            height:30
            anchor_x:'left'
            anchor_y:'bottom'
            Button:
                text:'lower bar'
```

my python code

```
    #:Python 3.6.6
from kivy.app import App
from kivy.uix.widget import Widget
from kivy.lang import Builder
Builder.load_file('Test.kv')
class UpperBar(Widget):
    pass

class MainField(Widget):
    pass

class LowerBar(Widget):
    pass

class Test(Widget):
    pass

class TestApp(App):
    def build(self):
        return Test()
    pass

if __name__ == '__main__':
    TestApp().run()
```

my result of upper code 
[image: my result of upper code]

[result of ikolim's suggestion](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cvOux.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `scroll_type` is an `OptionProperty` and defaults to `[‘content’]`.

Try adding [effect_cls: "ScrollEffect"](https://kivy.org/doc/stable/api-kivy.uix.scrollview.html#kivy.uix.scrollview.ScrollView.effect_cls), [scroll_type: ['bars']](https://kivy.org/doc/stable/api-kivy.uix.scrollview.html#kivy.uix.scrollview.ScrollView.scroll_type), and [bar_width: 8](https://kivy.org/doc/stable/api-kivy.uix.scrollview.html#kivy.uix.scrollview.ScrollView.bar_width) to the ScrollView.

## Snippets

```
        ScrollView:
            id:main_field
            do_scroll_y:True
            pos_hint: {'top': 1}

            bar_width: 8
            bar_color: 1, 0, 0, 1   # red
            bar_inactive_color: 0, 0, 1, 1   # blue
            effect_cls: "ScrollEffect"
            scroll_type: ['bars']
```

## Example

### main.py

```
from kivy.app import App
from kivy.uix.widget import Widget
from kivy.lang import Builder

Builder.load_file('main.kv')


class UpperBar(Widget):
    pass


class MainField(Widget):
    pass


class LowerBar(Widget):
    pass


class Test(Widget):
    pass


class TestApp(App):
    def build(self):
        return Test()


if __name__ == '__main__':
    TestApp().run()
```

### main.kv

```
#:kivy 1.10.1

<Test>:
    BoxLayout:
        orientation:'vertical'
        size:root.size

        AnchorLayout:
            id:upper_bar
            anchor_x:'left'
            anchor_y:'top'
            ActionBar:
                size_hint_y:None
                size_hint_x:1
                height:30
                ActionView:
                    ActionPrevious:
                        with_previous: False
                        title:''
                        app_icon:''
                    ActionGroup:
                        text:'File'
                        mode:'spinner'
                        ActionButton:
                            text:'Open'
                        ActionButton:
                            text:'Add New Obj'

        AnchorLayout:
            id:main_field
            anchor_x:'center'
            anchor_y:'center'
            size_hint_y:None
            size_hint_x:1
            height:root.height - upper_bar.height - lower_bar.height

            ScrollView:
                id:main_field
                do_scroll_y:True
                pos_hint: {'top': 1}

                bar_width: 8
                bar_color: 1, 0, 0, 1   # red
                bar_inactive_color: 0, 0, 1, 1   # blue
                effect_cls: "ScrollEffect"
                scroll_type: ['bars']

                ScatterLayout:
                    size_hint:[None,None]
                    size:1000,1000
                    canvas:
                        Rectangle:
                            pos:10,10
                            size:100,200
                        Rectangle:
                            pos:300,150
                            size:100,200

        AnchorLayout:
            id:lower_bar
            size_hint_y:None
            size_hint_x:1
            height:30
            anchor_x:'left'
            anchor_y:'bottom'

            Button:
                text:'lower bar'
```

## Output

[image: ScrollView]

Comment: Thank you for your quick response. I tried your suggestion but unfortunately unresolved my problem. There are two scroll bars(active and inactive). After moving first one, second one move and duplicate rectangles... Is there any problem in settings? But I have already tried re-install.

Comment: Could you capture the app running plus problem(s) in a video and share it with us.

Comment: Thank you for your comments. I am sorry that my response was delayed. I uploaded movie to here (https://ufile.io/y86e9).

Comment: As per your posted app/coding, my version does not show the third rectangle. I have updated my post with complete Python script and kv file. Try running my version to see whether you get only two rectangles when scrolled to the bottom.

Comment: Thank your for your suggestion! My problem is resolved! I sincerely appreciate your time and consideration.  However, I can not understand the cause of the problem. Where is the cause?

Comment: Above question is self-solved. "Builder.load_file('Test.kv')" is unnecessarily in my code. Removing this, my program is run.

Answer (score 0):

I think ikolim was on the right track by looking at setting some of the scrollviews attributes. Try setting `scroll_wheel_distance`. In the kivy documentation, it's described as the *Distance to move when scrolling with a mouse wheel*. It's default value is 20, so try halving it to 10! Hopefully, this will make your mouse wheel scrolls go the same distance as your touch screen scrolls!

Comment: Thank you for your suggestion, but unfortunately unresolved my problem.

Comment: I was able to change scroll speed. It looks like kivy makes duplicate ScrollView.